# what is the format for below Api call in retrofit?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

postman image with Api call format is attached below,

[image]

response is success when called through postman.

but Api response is failure when try through Code.

```
@GET("booking-list/{userId}")
fun getOrderHistoryList(@Path("userId") userId: Int):Observable<ResponseClass>
```

please help me to correcting format.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `@Path` to `@Query` like below, also `usedId` is a query parameter so you need to remove from path.

```
@GET("/booking-list")
fun getOrderHistoryList(@Query("userId") userId: Int):Observable<ResponseClass>
```

The query component is indicated by the first question mark ("?") character. For more information look at it [Query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Your get url should be

```
@GET("booking-list?userId={userId}")
```

Comment: In above mentioned URL **userId** is a `Query` parameter not the `Path` parameter.